# NIZK arguments for QAP GRO16 proof simulation

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

I'm studying how zero knowledge for quadratic arithmetic programs works ([GRO16](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/260.pdf) page 17) and try do understand proof simulation part.

If I understood right, if malicious party knows $\alpha , \beta ,\delta$ from setup it will be possible to construct $A,B,C $ that will satisfy verification equation. 
[image]

Are there are any other combinations of setup parameters that can help to simulate a valid proof?

Also, I would be grateful for a useful link / or research work where proof simulation for QAP this can be described.